# Не работает кнопка для выпадающей менюшки

Tags: html, jquery, html5, menu

Ребята, пробую сделать кнопку для выпадающего меню, но к сожалению не работает, прошу вас мне помочь.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  /* prepend menu icon */
  $('.nav').prepend('<div class="nav_menu">Menu</div>');

  /* toggle nav */
  $(".nav_menu").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="total">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <div>
        <img class="nav_menu" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_button.png" alt="button" border="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="nav_close" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_close.png" alt="cross_button" />
      </div>
      <div id="top_menu_outer">
        <div id="header_inner">
          <div id="top_menu">
            <div class="moduletable">
              <ul class="nav menu">
                <li class="item-109"><a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html">Контакты</a></li>
                <li class="item-112"><a href="/dostavka.html">Доставка и установка</a></li>
                <li class="item-111"><a href="/oplata.html">Оплата</a></li>
                <li class="item-110"><a href="/o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
                <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет) Css стили добавь в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

так:

```js
/* prepend menu icon */
$('.nav').prepend('<div class="nav_menu">Menu</div>');

/* toggle nav */
$(document).on("click",'.nav_menu', function(){
  $(".nav").slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <img class="nav_menu" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_button.png"  alt="button" border="0"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class="nav_close" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_close.png" alt="cross_button" />
            </div>
          
            <div id="top_menu_outer"> 
              <div id="header_inner">
                <div id="top_menu">     
                  <div class="moduletable">
                    <ul class="nav menu">
                      <li class="item-109">
                        <a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html" >
                          Контакты
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-112">
                        <a href="/dostavka.html" >
                          Доставка и установка
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-111">
                        <a href="/oplata.html" >
                          Оплата
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-110">
                        <a href="/o-magazine.html" >
                          О магазине
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-101 current active">
                        <a href="/" >
                          Главная
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

или так (чтобы кнопка не пряталась):

```js
/* prepend menu icon */
$('.moduletable').prepend('<div class="nav_menu">Menu</div>');

/* toggle nav */
$(document).on("click",'.nav_menu', function(){
  $(".nav").slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
 <div id="total">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <img class="nav_menu" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_button.png"  alt="button" border="0"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class="nav_close" src="/templates/shablon/images/menu_close.png" alt="cross_button" />
            </div>
          
            <div id="top_menu_outer"> 
              <div id="header_inner">
                <div id="top_menu">     
                  <div class="moduletable">
                    <ul class="nav menu">
                      <li class="item-109">
                        <a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html" >
                          Контакты
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-112">
                        <a href="/dostavka.html" >
                          Доставка и установка
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-111">
                        <a href="/oplata.html" >
                          Оплата
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-110">
                        <a href="/o-magazine.html" >
                          О магазине
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="item-101 current active">
                        <a href="/" >
                          Главная
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Кнопка создается динамически, поэтому клик по ней оформить можно с помощью `$(document).on("click", '.nav_menu', function(){...`